Trying to update column in GridDB but can't figure out why it is not updating
Im trying to update data in a GridDB container using the Python client. Ive set up my environment and written the following code to perform the update. The update operation does not seem to be working as the data stays the same.
Any ideas on what I may have done wrong here? Here is the documentation I was reading: https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/python/
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

try:
    store = factory.get_store(
        notification_member="239.0.0.1",
        notification_port=31999,
        cluster_name="myCluster",
        username="admin",
        password="admin"
    )
    container = store.get_container("myContainer")

    query = container.query("SELECT * FROM myContainer WHERE id = 1")
    rs = query.fetch()

    if rs.has_next():
        data = rs.next()
        data[2] = 35  # Update the age field

        # Put the updated row back into the container
        container.put(data)
        store.commit()
except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print("[", i, "]")
        print(e.get_error_code(i))
        print(e.get_message(i))

